# How to deal with DB datatype: 'bit' with javascript?

Tags: javascript, bit

I have a field in DB called 'active' and its data-type is 'BIT(1)'  (I just need it to be 1 or 0 only)

However, From js-application with `active='0'`, `active=0` and `active=false`, both cannot update the Database.

My System structure is:

```
js-frontend -> phpCaller -> phpAPI -> DB
```

Can someone teach me how to handle this problem?

Comment: In phpAPI like this:
"REPLACE INTO Staff ('name', 'active') VALUES (':name', ':active')"

Comment: Should it be done in the API not the Js?

Comment: Yes, translation between what JS needs and what the DB understands should be done in the API. Include the table definition, API function and JS call you currently have.